# Silverlight Localhost on Xampp

Tags: php, mysql, silverlight, json, silverlight-4.0

I am trying to retrive data to my SL application from PHP, MySQL service which is hosted locally on Xampp. 
I can see my php file running OK and deliver results via JSON  (http://localhost/silverlight/data.php) but SL cannot receive it. I belive it has something to do with correct URl path but I cant figure it out. Also I've putted clientaccesspolicy.xml file to allow cross-domain access but with no avail:(

```
 public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    ObservableCollection<ToDoItem> myToDoList = new ObservableCollection<ToDoItem>();
    string baseURI = "http://localhost/silverlight/";

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(baseURI + "data.php",UriKind.Absolute));
    }



    void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    { 

        if (e.Error == null && e.Result!= "")
        { JsonValue completeResult = JsonPrimitive.Parse(e.Result);
            string resultType = completeResult["returnType"].ToString().Replace("'", "").Trim();}
```

Comment: Could you please post your `clientaccesspolicy.xml` file and double-check that it's located at `http://localhost/clientaccesspolicy.xml`

Comment: The clientpolicy.xml taken from MSDN is:
[code]
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="SOAPAction">
        <domain uri="*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>[/code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `clientaccesspolicy.xml` file you use only allows cross-domain access for web service requests (as specified by `http-request-headers="SOAPAction"`)

For WebClient to work the way you use it, you need to enable content requests as well.

Try specifying `http-request-headers="*"` or `http-request-headers="SOAPAction,Content-Type"`.

Also, do check that the `clientaccesspolicy.xml` file is located at the root of the host, i.e. `http://localhost/clientaccesspolicy.xml`. Eventually when you decide to deploy your application, you'll have to make sure the file is placed in the root of the deployment host as well, e.g. `http://example.org/clientaccesspolicy.xml`

Comment: Thanks, I just putted the clientaccesspolicy.xml to the localhost and everything start to work :)